# CSS whats the difference between these two

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have two CSS files,

pic off the problem:

[image: Menu in IE9]

this pick shows no caps in the css. the css you see in the first pick is not that of the menu but that does not matter seeing it affects all css.

[image: IE9 right]

1: is the original
[link](http://pastebin.com/11y24Wgm)

2: the copy
[link](http://pastebin.com/sxtp7x8R)

### IE problem only

now my problem is that they do not act the same way as you would expect. the original shows the content as you would expect. the second does not show the drop down menu as it supposed to do.

the second thing is that if I look at the CSS on the in the browser it self than the original is all lowercase and the copy the tags are capitals. with seems to cause some of the trouble.

things I have checked:

- DOCTYPE
- ID
- Classes
- structure
- style tag vs .css

HTML
original:

```
<div style="margin-left: 50px;">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Login</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a>
    <ul id="help">
        <li>
        <img alt="" class="corner_inset_left" src="corner_inset_left.png" />
        <a href="#">General help</a>
        <img alt="" class="corner_inset_right" src="corner_inset_right.png" />
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
        <li class="last">
        <img alt="" class="corner_left" src="corner_left.png" />
        <img alt="" class="middle" src="dot.gif" />
        <img alt="" class="corner_right" src="corner_right.png" /> </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<img alt="" src="menu_right.png" style="float: left;" /> </div>
```

Copy http://pastebin.com/qsdz7pnj

Comment: Could you paste 2 screenshots on what's actually happening?
What version of Internet Explorer are you using?
IEx and other browsers behave differently when interpreting CSS.

Comment: Please post the code here in so far as it is relevant.

Comment: you should paste a link to your html or just paste the html code so that we can try it out

Comment: I juste pasted the html like asked

Comment: @limelight both 7,8 and 9 but I only realy care about 8 and 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve the CAPS in the CSS is a simple meta tag in the head.the caps in the script came from Quirks-mode. to stop the IE browser to use this mode use the meta tag shown here

```
<!-- Enable IE9 Standards mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Files are different - at least the second one contains additional `min-width: 130px;` in `#menu li` style. Also `#menu li ul` has different `color` set in those files. Maybe there's something more, haven't looked further.

Answer (score 1):

As Sergey Kudriavtsev says the files are different. The most significant potentially being:

Original:

```
#menu > li {
```

"Copy":

```
#menu li
```

And there is this again somewhere else. This is changing the selector and thus potentially what elements the style is applying to.

Are these files meant to be the same? The fact that you call them a copy makes me think they are but they are quite clearly not which makes me wonder if the underlying problem is just how they got to be different in the first place...

Comment: wierd the only thing I did was ctrl+c ctrl+v from one file to an other.